# How to add a unique code for every classroom in django

Tags: python, django

So, I am trying to build a simple elearning platform with django. What I want to achieve is that for every `classroom` that a teahcer creates, a unique 6 digit code is also generated, and when a student enters that code, he is admitted inside the classroom. I have a classroom model like this:

```
class Classroom:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.IntegerField()        

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I really don't think an `IntegerField` would do the work here. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UUID, A field for storing universally unique identifiers.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Answer (score 0):

Add a slug field in your Classroom model, override the `save()` method, and assign a random string as the slug. use `get_random_string` to generate a random string.

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

class Classroom:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.IntegerField()        
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = get_random_string(8,'0123456789') # 8 characters, only digits.  
        Super(Classroom, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}-{self.slug}'
```